# Позиционный звук SKAudioNode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, аудио, spritekit

В SpriteKit есть SKAudioNode, он вроде как дает позиционный звук в зависимости от расстояния двух нодов, и все работает, чем ближе "слушатель" к источнику звука, тем звук сильнее.

Но проблема в том, что какое бы расстояние между двумя нодами не было, звук все равно слышен на определенной громкости, и потом просто усиливается при приближении. А надо что бы он при старте не был слышен, и потом при приближении начинал усиливаться с нуля. Иначе говоря нужно настроить радиус в котором будет работать позиционирование.. если "слушатель" вне радиуса, то звука совсем нет.

Возможно ли такое реализовать стандартными средствами?

**UPD:** Если такое нельзя реализовать с помощью SKAudioNode, то в какую сторону надо копать?
Самое главное чтобы звук запускался только тогда, когда объект, испускающий его, появляется на экране.

Comment: пробовали громкость для года менять, например сделать 0.5. я так понимаю при этом максимальное расстояние должно сократиться вдвое.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko к сожалению это ничего не меняет, просто уменьшается общая громкость звука.

Comment: мы про одно и то же говорим? я имею ввиду нод который производит звук, а не listener node

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko да, именно это) Просто уменьшается общая громкость нода который воспроизводит звук, остальные звуки остаются неизменными)